# Passing context to template through ngOutletContext in Angular2

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular2-template, angular2-directives

I have a component to which I am passing a template. Inside of this component I would like to pass context so that I could display data.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-component',
  providers: [],
  template: `
    <template [ngTemplateOutlet]="templ" [ngOutletContext]="{isVisible: true}">
    </template>
  `
})
export class MyElementComponent implements OnInit {
    @ContentChild(TemplateRef) templ;
    constructor(){}
}
```

Now when using component inside of other component:

```
<my-component>
    <template>
        {{isVisible ? 'yes!' : 'no'}}
    </template>
</my-component>
```

So in `my-component` I am passing a template which is handled in it's class by `@ContentChild` with name `templ`.

Then, in `my-component`'s template i am passing `templ` to `ngTemplateOutlet` and additionally, I am passing context using `ngOutletContext` which has `isVisible` set to `true`.

we should see `yes!` on the screen but it seems that context is never passed.

My angular version:

```
"@angular/common": "^2.3.1",
"@angular/compiler": "^2.3.1",
"@angular/core": "^2.3.1",
```

Comment: I'm facing the same issue. You're right, context is never passed. This is because template that you're passing as content to <my-component> is actually bound to the context of <my-component>'s host. I'd like to get this working as well, but I don't see any way yet.

Comment: @AlexanderLeonov Look my answer. I've found it.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

After a long time, I made it.

Example with single value:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-component',
  providers: [],
  template: `
    <template [ngTemplateOutlet]="templ" [ngOutletContext]="{isVisible: true}">
    </template>
  `
})
export class MyElementComponent implements OnInit {
    @ContentChild(TemplateRef) templ;
    constructor(){}
}

<my-component>
    <template let-isVisible="isVisible">
        {{isVisible ? 'yes!' : 'no'}}
    </template>
</my-component>
```

Example with loop:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-component',
  providers: [],
  template: `
    <div *ngFor="let element of data">
        <template [ngTemplateOutlet]="templ" [ngOutletContext]="{element: element}">
        </template>
    </div>
  `
})
export class MyElementComponent implements OnInit {
    @ContentChild(TemplateRef) templ;
    constructor(){
        this.data = [{name:'John'}, {name:'Jacob'}];
    }
}

--- 

<my-component>
    <template let-element="element">
        {{element.name}}
    </template>
</my-component>
```

Result:

```
<div>John</div>
<div>Jacob</div>
```

Answer (score 17):

Heads up ngOutletContext is deprecated and renamed as ngTemplateOutletContext.

Search the change log for "NgTemplateOutlet#ngTemplateOutletContext"

[CHANGELOG](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md)

Comment: So why was this down voted? Just because I didn't short format the CHANGELOG link? Should I not post helpful information? Please help me understand as I am turned off to helping further

Comment: My original comment has since been up voted. Encouraged to help again!